# Modify array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Javascript I have an array of dates, for example:

```
["2018-04-25", 
"2018-04-25", 
"2018-04-26", 
"2018-04-27", 
"2018-04-28", 
"2018-04-28"]
```

How can I recognise duplicate dates and change them to false so the values become:

```
["2018-04-25", 
false, 
"2018-04-26", 
"2018-04-27", 
"2018-04-28", 
false]
```

This is what it needs to be.

Thanks

Comment: `arr = ["2018-04-25", 
false, 
"2018-04-26", 
"2018-04-27", 
"2018-04-28", 
false]`

Comment: arr[1]=false; arr[5]=false;

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do that, but the code needs to recognise duplicate dates and change them for me.

Comment: @udarts this sould be edited into your question (mplungjan already did). The two previous comments are pointing to the fact that you didn't specify an algorithm and that it's up to the answerer to come with one. Sure "duplicate dates should be mapped to false" seems like a good one, but so does "the second and sixth dates should be mapped to false"

Comment: is the array sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sorted array, you could check the predecessor and return `false` if the same, otherwide the value.

```js
var array = ["2018-04-25", "2018-04-25", "2018-04-26", "2018-04-27", "2018-04-28", "2018-04-28"];

array = array.map((v, i, a) => a[i - 1] !== v && v);
    
console.log(array);
```

For unsorted arrays and respecting the first same date, as mentioned by [Kevin Hoerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8833540/kevin-hoerr) in the comments, take `indexOf` and check against the actual index.

```js
var array = ["2018-04-25", "2018-04-25", "2018-04-26", "2018-04-27", "2018-04-28", "2018-04-28"];

array = array.map((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i && v);
    
console.log(array);
```

If you have a complete ISO date, you could use just the date without time. This approach needs sorted data.

```js
var array = ['2018-04-14T13:00:00+02:00', '2018-04-15T08:45:00+02:00', '2018-04-15T10:00:00+02:00', '2018-04-22T08:45:00+02:00', '2018-04-22T10:00:00+02:00', '2018-04-29T08:45:00+02:00', '2018-04-29T10:00:00+02:00'];

array = array.map((v, i, a) => (a[i - 1] || '').slice(0, 10) !== v.slice(0, 10) && v);
    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: You could modify this slightly to cover all cases too pretty easily, at some performance cost - change the `a[i - 1] !== v` to `a.indexOf(v) === i` to check if it's the first.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: The only question I have, what if the dates are like: `[ '2018-04-14T13:00:00+02:00',
  '2018-04-15T08:45:00+02:00',
  '2018-04-15T10:00:00+02:00',
  '2018-04-22T08:45:00+02:00',
  '2018-04-22T10:00:00+02:00',
  '2018-04-29T08:45:00+02:00',
  '2018-04-29T10:00:00+02:00']` You can see some double dates in there, only the time is different. I thought of using momentjs to change the format just for checking, but keep it as it is.

Comment: do you need only the first same date of the array? and should the result contain only dates, without hour, minutes, etc?

Comment: Well for comparing, only date is easier, but later on (further in the code) I want to check if the dates are in the array (compared to items) and then display dates if is not false. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: not, really, how should look the wanted result of the full iso dates?

Comment: By default the dates are shown as: `[ '2018-04-14T13:00:00+02:00', '2018-04-15T08:45:00+02:00', '2018-04-15T10:00:00+02:00', '2018-04-22T08:45:00+02:00', '2018-04-22T10:00:00+02:00', '2018-04-29T08:45:00+02:00', '2018-04-29T10:00:00+02:00']` This is what I would like to keep, but I am not sure if this is easy to compare (for the function above), as it also contains time. If it can be done with dates this way, I prefer it.

Comment: if that is the result, you want, you get it, because all strings are different.

Comment: This is the format I get the dates in, to use them later, I prefer to keep them like this (as it makes printing the date it self easier later in the code), but change the duplicate dates (not times) with false. That works if I only use dates (as stated above), but in this format it will never by false, even if the dates are the same.

Comment: Example, the default format should be something like this, after the comparing: `[ '2018-04-14T13:00:00+02:00', '2018-04-15T08:45:00+02:00', false, '2018-04-22T08:45:00+02:00', false, '2018-04-29T08:45:00+02:00', false]`

Answer (score 0):

forEach seems to be easier to read than the map and reduce I see here

```js
var data = ["2018-04-25","2018-04-25","2018-04-26","2018-04-27","2018-04-28","2018-04-28"];
var newArr = [];
data.forEach(function(x) {
  newArr.push(newArr.includes(x) ? false : x)
});
console.log(newArr)
```